# I have a jquery script that returns a string. How do I get it to return a white space character at the end?

Tags: jquery, string, whitespace, padding

Here is what I have:

```
                                $(this).text(function(){
                                    if(this.title <=45)
                                        return 'Done ';
                                    else
                                        return 'Incomplete ';

                                });
```

but I want the string that gets outputted to show the final white space char.

It currently outputs it so that I get "Done" I want "Done "

Thanks!

Comment: I posted an answer to your question, but... is this something that could be done in css instead? For example, are you trying to add some spacing between two elements? If so, css would be preferable to essentially hard-coding styling into data.

Comment: Yes this could have been done in css as well, I could have padded/margined the text, but I had my code set up this way (this is only a snippet to give an example of the issue I was having - the code itself is complicated and would have required me to change a lot of other stuff if I wanted to configure this in css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change it like this:

```
$(this).html(function(){
    if(this.title <=45)
        return 'Done&nbsp;';
    else
        return 'Incomplete&nbsp;';
});
```

Note that you need to use `html()` and not `text()`

Also, I would probably make this a little more concise:

```
$(this).html((this.title <= 45 ? 'Done' : 'Incomplete') + '&nbsp;');
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone and this was it! I had already tried &nbsp before, but it wasn't working because I was using text() instead of html().

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
   return "Done"+ "&nbsp";
```

where `"&nbsp"` add whitespace.

or if you have a div/span id ,then another possibility is

```
$("#target").append(" ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these strings : `Done&nbsp;` and `Incomplete&nbsp;`

Answer (score 0):

The HTML compiler strips all the excess whitespaces in a page, except between words. So if you really need the whitespaces, use the HTML code `&nbsp;` as many times you need them.

Answer (score 0):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/GzJgr/)***

If you want whitespace to show up in markup, use the `<pre>` element. If you cannot use the `pre` element, then use the `pre` css style.

```
element.style.whiteSpace="pre";
```